# Common use cases of RMAN restore/recovery

Tags: oracle-11g, rman

To test our Oracle backup & recovery process, I would like to simulate some common fail case scenarios. Any suggestions?

Comment: Move this to SO?

Answer (score 1):

The two most common ones that we've seen in production:

- Unexpected power outage during writes

  - To make this more critical, run RAID5, remove your battery backup but leave write caching turned ON. This will virtually guarantee corruption
- Accidentally drop a critical system table